# how to process to retrieve records from another table based on comma separated values in column?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like the followings,

```
USER TABLE :
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
+     id      +    password   +    role_id    +
+-------------+---------------+---------------+ 
+      1      +     values    +     1, 2, 3   +  
+-------------+---------------+---------------+

ROLE TABLE :
+-------------+---------------+
+  role_id    +   role_name   +    
+-------------+---------------+
+      1      +     admin     +     
+-------------+---------------+
+      2      +     user      +     
+-------------+---------------+
+      3      +    vendor     +     
+-------------+---------------+
```

now, tried to retrieve a records form role table based on user table role_id, but i have retrieve top most record from following query

```
SELECT role_name FROM Role where role_id=(Select role_id from User where id=1);
```

one record i got,i.e)

```
+---------------+
+   role_name   +    
+---------------+
+    admin      +    
+---------------+
```

Please Friends help me to solve this, Thank You in advance.

Comment: It is very bad database design to save values as a csv. You should change it. What  is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma separated values violate RDBMS normalization rules. However in case you can't normalize it at this point, you may use `FIND_IN_SET()` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM role
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(role_id, (SELECT role_id FROM user WHERE id=1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can change your structure and [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it ,storing comma separated associations is really a bad idea if you are not able to change your structure then you can use `find_in_set()`

```
SELECT role_name 
FROM role r
join `user` u on (find_in_set(r.role_id,replace(u.role_id,' ','')) > 0)
where u.id=1
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a41e5/2)

A normalized way would be create a junction table which will hold user id and role id e.g

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles
    (`role_id` int(11), `user_id` int(11))
;
```

For user 1 `user_roles` will have rows for user 1 something like

```
-----------------
role_id | user_id
-----------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

Now your query will only use join and will perform much better than `find_in_set` approach

```
SELECT role_name 
FROM role r
join `user_roles` u using(role_id)
where u.user_id=1
```

[`DEMO 2`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0cb4/2)